# categorical search in android

Tags: android, api, maps

I want to search phrase "metro station" in maps and return the first result and display it in my app.
I also want to navigate to the result returned by maps from my current location.
can anyone help? I think categorical search will come to my aid.
can anyone tell me how to implement it?
thanks